# Registrer new user using API guard?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have changed settings in `Auth.php` file on the default API guard:

```
'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'api',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
```

Now when I try to register a new user using web form I get error:

```
FatalThrowableError in RegistersUsers.php line 32:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\TokenGuard::login()
```

How can I fix it and register new user with RESTful mechanism?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Registration error in Laravel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39321584/registration-error-in-laravel)