# Registration error in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I use the default `auth/registration` in Laravel 5.3.

When I try to register new user I get  error:

```
FatalThrowableError in RegistersUsers.php line 33:
    Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\TokenGuard::login()
```

I have made some changes in configuration Laravel:

```
'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'api',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
```

So, by default I use api guard

Comment: in which configuration file you made changes ?

Comment: you probably defined an api guard which is not capable of logging someone in since apis work with tokens to ensure authentication - therfore your "TokenGuard" probably just doesnt have a login method as explained in the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The authentication driver `api` you are trying to use is TokenBased. That means the server will issue your client a Token on successful authentication using credentials. Then, client can present this token to server while making the request to identify itself.

As given in [laravel git](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Auth/TokenGuard.php), there isn't any method as `login()`.

To use the TokenBased Authentication, here's the good [guide](https://gistlog.co/JacobBennett/090369fbab0b31130b51)

Comment: I know, but how can I register new user? This articles does not explain how to do that

Comment: @Babaev registration process wont change. It will remain the same... provide the registration form to user and add the data to your users table.. right ?

Comment: I think your data is inserting properly in the DB. But if you check the `register` method in your `AuthController` there must be a call to `login` method after data insertion.. You would need to change to return the token. You can always override the `postRegister()` method in your `AuthController` to implement this..

Comment: I use Laravel 5.3, It does not have `AuthController`, I need that user can register using RESTful mechanism and standart web form.